# Apex classes - Valid statement

Tags: apex

I stumble upon a blog/question which I thought was very interesting and what to share with you all here the question is:

Valid statement about Apex classes:

```
1 a exception classes must end with the world exception
2 a class can have multiple levels of inner classes
3 the default modifier for a class is private
```

I have looked at the [Salesforce docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_defining.htm) but could not find the #1 and I thought to ask you here is the above statement is true (#1,#2,#3) for the Apex class?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These are not all true.

1. Classes which extend Exception must end with the word Exception. You can see this is true in [Creating Custom Exceptions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apex_workbook.meta/apex_workbook/apex7_5.htm).

   > To create your custom exception class, extend the built-in Exception class and make sure your class name ends with the word Exception.
2. A class can have only one level of inner classes. You can see this in the [Force.com Apex Code Developer's Guide](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_apex_language_reference.pdf) on page 56.

   > In Apex, you can define top-level classes (also called outer classes) as well as inner classes, that is, a class defined within another class.
   >   You can only have inner classes one level deep. For example:
   >   
   >   `public class myOuterClass {
   >       // Additional myOuterClass code here
   >       class myInnerClass {
   >           // myInnerClass code here
   >       }
   >   }`
3. You cannot have a private top-level class. It would not have any accessible functionality and would just be a waste of space. The default modifier for pretty much everything *within* a top-level Apex class, however is private. The only counter-example I can think of is getters/setters, which inherit from their property. Below, you can see that a getter without a specified level of access can still be public.

`public String someProperty { get; private set; }`

Regardless, the truth of this statement is outlined in the article you link to in your OP:

> The private access modifier declares that this class is only known locally, that is, only by this section of code. This is the default access for inner classes—that is, if you don't specify an access modifier for an inner class, it is considered private. This keyword can only be used with inner classes.

Comment: Thanks Adrian, can you point me to the doc for #2 I'm looking but could not find.

Comment: @AbuHamzah I linked to the Force.com Apex Code Developer's Guide. It's worth reading through as much of it as you are able.

Comment: my understanding is #3 is just targeting the class, not the members of a class. if so, the default access modifier for inner class is private, but for top level outer classes we hv to specify either public or global.

Answer (score 3):

Its all available in Salesforce docs but got scattered across few places..

[Creating Custom Exceptions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apex_workbook.meta/apex_workbook/apex7_5.htm)

> To create your custom exception class, extend the built-in Exception class and make sure your class name ends with the word Exception

I did a quick test by creating a class extending Exception class without following the naming convention and got the below error

> TestEx: Classes extending Exception must have a name ending in 'Exception'

[Inner Class (taken from Apex Class Definition)](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_defining.htm)

> You can only have inner classes one level deep

[Access Modifiers (taken from Apex Class Definition)](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_defining.htm)

Private is the default access modifier **Only for Inner classes**

For Top level / Outer classes you have to explicitly define an access modifier. otherwise you will get an error like this

> Top-level type must have public or global visibility

**So, out of the 3, the first one is the valid statement about Apex class.**

Comment: When you say, "the first one is the valid statement about Apex class," you imply that #3 is false, when it is in fact true. #2 is the only false statement.

Comment: #3 is false becos private is NOT the default access modifier for all class.. its only default for inner class. for top level outer classes you have to explicitly mark them as public or global.